# How to set the size of the main dialog in a MFC dialog based application

Tags: mfc

I'm trying to create a dialog based application using MFC, it seems that I can change the dialog size by dragging the corner of the dialog in the resource view, but is there a way to set the dialog size numerically such as 800 by 600?

Comment: In the resource view or in the code ?

Comment: @Blacktempel, preferably in the resource view.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The size of a dialog is always calculated in DLUs (Dialog Base Units). This DLUs scale to pixels depending on the size of the dialogs font.

So inside the resource it it isn't possible to fix a dialog size to exactly a given pixel size. You need to do this at runtime with MoveWindow/SetWindowPos

More Infos about DLUs here in [MapDialogRect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645502(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: If my crystal ball is right, the question is about specifying size of the dialog (let it be in DLU) digitally, in the property page (like you can do in C# Form Editor, or in Bitmap Editor) instead of dragging the corner and watching the readings in the right-bottom corner to hit that 800 mark.